# Selecting multiple rows as one row with "AS"

Tags: sql-server

If I have a table of users, for example, and I want to include the users in a query like so:

```
SELECT gameId, player1id, player2id, users.username as player1, users.username as player2
FROM players, users
WHERE gameId = 2 AND player1.id = player1id AND player2.id = player2id
```

How would I handle the  part of the select statement where I am getting the player names? I know what I have is incorrect but I am stuck trying to figure out the proper syntax for this.

When all is said and done I am trying to get 1 row to return that has 2 columns on the end named "player1" and "player2" with their respective usernames.

Comment: I'm going to have to vote to close this unless the information requested in my answer is forthcoming.

Answer (score 1):

Probably:

```
SELECT 
  p.gameId, 
  p.player1id, 
  p.player2id, 
  u1.username as player1, 
  u2.username as player2
FROM dbo.players AS p
INNER JOIN dbo.users AS u1
  ON p.player1id = u1.id
INNER JOIN dbo.users AS u2
  ON p.player2id = u2.id
WHERE p.gameId = 2;
```

This is 2015. You should not be using old-style join syntax from the 70s; join us in this century and realize the benefits of proper, modern, explicit joins ([see this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)). Also, while coding conventions are largely subjective, don't be afraid to use some carriage returns once in a while ([see this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2008/10/30/my-stored-procedure-best-practices-checklist)). Note the use of schema prefix on every object reference ([see this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)), proper alias references prefixing *all* column instances - I mean, for all I know, `gameId` is in the `users` table - ([see this blog post](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/best-practices-referencing-columns)), and the ever-important statement terminator ([see this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons)).

If you're bored and you want to read up on lots of other opinions on bad habits and best practices, [I have a whole checklist](https://sqlblog.org/bad-habits).

Answer (score 1):

Post the DDL for players (same for users). This is the CREATE TABLE My_Table (fieldname... fieldlist); statement for both tables.

You've no table player1 (**or** player2) - and then you're trying to use aliases for field names as table names? @RobFarley has given you a clue here (maybe).

I really don't know where to start, except to advise you to read some basic SQL books/sites. Take the site [tour](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tour), read the "[help us to help you](http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/)" blog (and the links within - bottom left of page and also by @Aaron Bertrand) and visit the [help centre](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help) (top right).

Tip no.1 - remove your aliases and `WHERE` clause from your SQL and see what you get (prob. a mess! - `CROSS JOIN`), but try and work from there. Do you have anyone who can mentor you, at least intially?

Post your table structures (as above), some sample data (in the form of DML - i.e. SQL statements - INSERT INTO My_Table (field_list...) VALUES (Value_list...), the result you want and the logic you used to get that result.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is:

```
FROM players as player1, players as player2, users
```

The better answer is for you to learn how to use the ON clause.